# В браузере FireFox не работает медиа запрос prefers-color-scheme

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

Я использую актуальную на данный момент версию браузера FireFox 93.0, согласно [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=prefers-color-scheme) браузер поддерживает данный медиа запрос.
Но через css

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {...}
```

не получается стилизовать,
так же

```
window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches
```

в темной версии всегда возвращает `false`. В других браузерах все отрабатывает корректно.

Подскажите может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и знает решение?

Comment: А вы уверены, что в вашем Firefox реально включена тёмная тема и эти запросы реально должны срабатывать?

Comment: Да, переключаюсь именно на дефолтную "Тёмная Тема с тёмной цветовой гаммой.", от автора Mozila, версия 1.2, последнее обновление темы 5сентября 2021г.